# How to schedule the execution of code at 9 : 00 AM

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, swift3

My app based on LocalNotifications in iOS 10.

I have a "Note" entity with "Reminder Date" (Daily, Weekly etc.). Every day I want a check: for today I have notes to remind or not. In case - if the user has only weekly-remind notes, how to check on what day of the week need to show notification.

Thanks

Comment: You can't execute code on a set time, your best option is to set an [`UILocalNotifiction`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilocalnotification) for the note that reminding.

Comment: Can I create notification without user interactions?

Comment: You aks permission to send the user notification, After permission is granted you can schedule a `UILocalNotifiction` with a date on which it should be shown. You can repeat `UILocalNotifiction` daily, weekly, monthly, .... Just keep in mind that you can only schedule 64 notifications.

Comment: Thank you for information about quantity of scheduled notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any possibility to execute your code on a specified time. Instead if your app is working on that time you can execute anything as you want. Otherwise application will not be in memory.

Use the code below to get the current time:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

And check if time matches 9:00 AM
Not: only when your application is running.

Making a notification from APNS server is possible even if application is not working

Comment: @Kostantin I think my answer was helpful to you.please let me know if not.